# Access #Name? on control when doing something simple

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I've had this problem before with certain reports, and it would work sometimes and sometimes not.

But I'm doing something super simple that I thought I've done a thousand times.

I have two forms. Button on Form1 opens form2. Form2 has no record source linking it to Form1, but is related. So on form2 I have a control that references a control on form1.

It's a blank unbound textbox, and I set it's control source to `[Forms]![form1]![foo]`

When I open form2, I get `#Name?` in that textbox instead of the text in `[Forms]![form1]![foo]`.

Form1 is open at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're talking about the `ControlSource` property, make sure to include the `=` sign.

This works for me as the `ControlSource` for a text box ... when `Form3` is open in Form View ...

```
=[Forms]![Form3]![txtNote]
```

Comment: Wow I really need to shake off the rust.

Answer (score 0):

I like to reference controls with the dot notation instead of the bang notation.  Does it help to change it to the example below?

```
[Forms]![form1].[foo]
```

or if there are no spaces in the name of the form or the control.

```
Forms!form1.foo
```